# How can assembly be used to add bytes together?

Tags: assembly

To store data on the blockchain, a storage container `bytes[6] data` is used, each array stores maximum amount based on block gas limit. Can assembly be used to add those 6 arrays together, and return one single bytes array?

```
function getData() public view {
    uint length;
    for(uint i = 0; i<6; i++) {
        length += data[i].length;
    }
    bytes memory result = new bytes(length);

    uint index = 32; // bytes is an array, and in EVM the first 
                     // 32 bytes of an array stores the length
                     // of the array, so add data 32 byte in

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        bytes memory oneSixth = new bytes(data[i].length);
        oneSixth = data[i];
        assembly {
            mstore(add(result, index), add(oneSixth, 32))
        }
        index += data[i].length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK found how to get it to work, from looking at this post,
[Concat two bytes arrays with Assembly](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32003/concat-two-bytes-arrays-with-assembly?rq=1)

had to add `mload(add(oneSixth, 32)`

So instead of

```
mstore(add(result, index), add(oneSixth, 32))
```

it is

```
mstore(add(result, index), mload(add(oneSixth, 32)))
```

update: mload could only load 32 byte, so can not be used to load arbitrarily long byte arrays